# Problem with CUPS/texttopdf and "Noto" truetype fonts

Tags: printing, fonts

I'm having a problem with the **texttopdf** CUPS filter.

When I attempt to print a plain ASCII file (as simple as "Hello world"), **texttopdf** aborts:

```
D [17/May/2020:11:48:37 -0700] [Job 513] Sending data to printer.
D [17/May/2020:11:48:37 -0700] [Job 513] Set job-printer-state-message to "Sending data to printer.", current level=INFO
D [17/May/2020:11:48:37 -0700] [Job 513] Unsupported OTF font / glyf table 
D [17/May/2020:11:48:37 -0700] [Job 513] Brother-HL-1240-series: fontembed/sfnt.c:651: otf_get_width: Assertion `0\' failed.
D [17/May/2020:11:48:37 -0700] [Job 513] PID 1520973 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf) crashed on signal 6.
D [17/May/2020:11:48:37 -0700] [Job 513] Input is empty, outputting empty file.
```

After a considerable amount of detective work, I discovered that if I disable the "noto" (No Tofu) **truetype** fonts, by moving them out of **/usr/share/fonts/truetype**, the problem goes away.

However, the audio editor **audacity** hangs when I do that (don't ask me why), and since I do a fair amount of audio editing, not to mention that the "solution" really isn't a solution, simply deleting the "noto" fonts is not an acceptable solution.

I've searched around, looking for configuration files or the like but have thus far come up empty handed.

This is on Ubuntu 20.04.

apt-show-versions tells me:

cups:amd64/focal-security 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 uptodate

cups-filters:amd64/focal 1.27.4-1 uptodate

if that's of interest.

One further bit of information: if I invoke **texttopdf** from the command line,it produces a valid PDF as a reward for my efforts, so it appears to be something in the CUPS filter/tool chain that is involved.

Comment: Which version of Linux and which release number is in use? Different releases have different tools. Please click [edit] and add that to your question; please do not use Add Comment as that's our one-way channel to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, apparently, is in one of the "noto" fonts, **NotoColorEmoji**, and **texttopdf** was choking on it.

I fixed this by creating the file **/etc/fonts/local.conf** and adding the lines

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <selectfont>
    <rejectfont>
      <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf</glob>
    </rejectfont>
  </selectfont>
</fontconfig>
```

Then run **fc-cache -f -v** to rebuild the font cache.

This disables the offending font and all is well.

BTW, credit where credit is due: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534284/reject-all-fonts-from-a-directory-except-one-with-fontconfig

Further note:

I decided to download the source code for **cups-filters** and the abort is indeed an assert in the library **libfontembed** in the function **otf_get_width**, snippeted here:

```c
  // ensure hmtx is there
  if (!otf->hmtx) {
    if (otf_load_more(otf)!=0) {
      assert(0);
      return -1;
    }
  }
```

***Sheesh***. . .

Comment: Did you file a bug report? I have the same issue, but disabling the Emoji font makes the use of discord or social media in general real painful. I would go and file myself, but I have no clue what would be the best place to do so.

It **is** Ubuntu-specific. I tried `inxi -Fxr | lp` from three 20.04 Laptops and a Manjaro one. All Ubuntu laptops printed only blocks, the Manjaro one put out a correct page. All to the same printer.

Comment: I personally find the whole notion social media to be painful in and of itself, so not having emojis is just fine with me. Maybe I'll install some other OS and test but dealing with this has already cost me an entire day of work so I'm loath to spend much more time on it.

Comment: Understandable. I tried to file a bug report on Github for `cups`, but got told that it doesn't happen on Fedora and should go to `cups-filters` anyway. Maybe I try my luck there to get it fixed.

Comment: Way to go @TeakwoodJOverclutch!  This problem bedeviled me for 6 hours until I stumbled across this answer.  If you monitor this, could you perhaps described how you narrowed this down to a problem with the Noto emojii font, in case some other font causes a problem?

Comment: @Daniel Doherty -- I honestly don't recall the exact process I used to figure this out. I think I might've looked at all the elements in the tool chain one by one that's about all I can dredge up from my recollection. Glad I could be of help to someone, though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I'm not allowed to comment.
But I vote you raise a bug report. I'm seeing this in the latest version of kubuntu 21.10 (so I guess its in ubuntu).

I'd raise it against kubuntu  (or your distro) they can bounce it up to cups/cups-filter , if it's not something distro specific .... and I guess they may in turn push it out the fonts developer. Any it needs a bug number.

Comment: “This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker."